# Unwanted WordPress redirection

Tags: redirect, malware

When I access my website on a computer, everythiing is okay. But when I access my website from my mobile, it redirects me on websites with hazard and p*rn. I found a malware on my website so I removed it but it still redirects me when I try to access my website on a phone. Really strange and I don´t know how can I fix this. I checked all index.php, index.html, theme files, header.php, footer.php, functions.php.....Nothing there. How can I fix this?

Comment: If your servers got malware infected try to find an expert who takes alook ath them....

Comment: it's hard to say anything without looking at this particular instance. So provide a bit more details.